# Partial fill with \dotfill using xtabular and memoir

Tags: tables

With this mwe code, I get an incomplete fill between columns 3 and 4 (marked as col 2 and 3, just before B-Q3 in row marked 5.) I've marked each col with @{} with the intent of eliminating inter col whitespace. What am I doing wrong?

```
% arara: xelatex: { shell: true }
% mco.tex -- Compare Center Counter Through 15 Editions of MCO
% Hugh S. Myers
% Last Change: 22:55:54 08:10:2021
%
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xtab}

\newcommand{\prepTable}[2]{
  \tablefirsthead{
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{\large Centre Counter.}\\
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{1\;{}P---K4, P---Q4.}\\
    \DoubleRule{1em}{1.65pt}{1em}
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{2\hspace{.65em}P\x P, Q\x P;\;\;3\hspace{.65em}Kt---Q\,B3, Q---Q\,R4.}&&&\\
    & \ral{c}{\LARGE*} & & & &\\[-1.2em]
    #1 \\
  }
  \tablehead{
    \multicolumn{#2}{l}{\small\emph{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    #1 \\
    \midrule
  }
  \tabletail{
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{#2}{r}{\small\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
  }
  \tablelasttail{\specialrule{0.1pt}{1em}{1pt}}
}
\newcommand*{\ral}[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\DoubleRule}[3]{\specialrule{0.1pt}{#1}{0pt}\specialrule{0.1pt}{#2}{#3}}
\newfontface{\Chess}{SkakNew-Figurine.otf}
\setromanfont[Ligatures={Common}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Linux Libertine O}
\newcommand{\x}{\hspace{0.1em}{\Chess X}\hspace{0.1em}}
\newcommand{\M}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{r}{#1}}

\begin{document}
  \prepTable{& \ral{c}{1}  & \ral{c}{2}  &\ral{c}{3}  &\ral{c}{4}  &\ral{c}{5}}{6}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{xtabular}{@{}p{1.5em}*{5}{@{}p{0.166\linewidth}}}
    \M{4}  & P---Q4            &            &                &                 & \\
           & Kt---K\,B3\       &            &                &                 & \\
    \M{5}  & Kt---B3\dotfill   & .\dotfill  & B---Q3\dotfill & B---Q\,B4       & \\
           & B---Kt5\dotfill   & B---B4     & Kt---B3        & Kt---B3\dotfill & B---Kt5\\
    \end{xtabular}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spanning entry

```
\multicolumn{3}{l}{2\hspace{.65em}P\x P, Q\x P;\;\;3\hspace{.65em}Kt---Q\,B3, Q---Q\,R4.}
```

is wider than the three columns that it spans so the third column is extended. However that is a `p` column and the inner parbox in that column is still the specified width.

If I read this correctly that cell doesn't need to only span three columns, you can allow it to span 4

```
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{2\hspace{.65em}P\x P, Q\x P;\;\;3\hspace{.65em}Kt---Q\,B3, Q---Q\,R4.}&&\\
```

Comment: As you say, it can span 4! Or for that matter, it can span 6. Thanks for spotting that problem.